# Мультизагрузка изображений на сайт

Tags: php, dual-boot

Всем привет, у меня такая проблема - есть форма загрузки изображений на сайт и есть обработчик, я хочу изменить код чтобы загружать сразу несколько изображений на сайт.
С формой я вроде бы разобрался, а вот обработчик не дает этого сделать(
Вот кусок кода формы, отредактированный мною:

```
<section id="modal-upload" class="modal upload hide">
<a class="badge-overlay-close btn-close" href="#">?</a>
<section id="upload-file">
<form id="form-modal-post-image" class="modal" action="{$baseurl}/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onsubmit="return GAG.UploadController.validateForm();">
<input type="hidden" id="jsid-submit-form-csrftoken" name="images[]" multiple="true"/>
<div id="jsid-disable-mask">
<center><p class="lead">{$lang98}</p></center>
<div class="field photo">
<label style="display:none;">
<a id="jsid-upload-url-btn" class="" href="javascript:void(0);">{$lang99}</a> / 
<a id="jsid-upload-file-btn" class="upload-selected" href="javascript:void(0);">{$lang100}</a>
</label>
<input id="jsid-upload-url-input" class="hide" type="url" name="url" placeholder="Ссылка на видео" value="" />
<div id="jsid-upload-file-input" class="file-field ">
<input class="file text" type="file" name="images[]" multiple="true" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" />
</div>
<p id="jsid-upload-content-error" class="error-message hide"></p>
</div>
```

А вот куски кода обработчика:

```
if($submit_sec == "1")
{
if(isset($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'])){$uploadedimage = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];}else{$uploadedimage = "";}
if($uploadedimage == "")
{
```

и

```
$myconvertimg = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
```

Что нужно поменять в коде обработчика чтобы произошла загрузка сразу нескольких изображений? Помогите, плиз.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $i => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_img = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //тут какие то действия с изображениями

        $uploadedimage[] = $tmp_img;

    }
}

echo json_encode($uploadedimage);
```

это выведет массив с временными названиями всех загруженных файлов

Comment: Добавил этот код в обработчик - при загрузке изображений выдает ошибку 500.

Comment: уберите 
echo json_encode($uploadedimage);

Comment: Тоже самое - ошибка 500.

Comment: Скиньте больше кода обработчика без этого помочь не могу

Comment: http://gag.4fun.one/submit.txt - Вот весь файл целиком, только в txt формате.